# How can i find the visibility mesh from a point inside a given mesh?

Tags: visibility, computational-geometry, mesh

I am trying to find the points inside a given mesh from which the whole mesh is visible. I created an algorithm for the 2D problem but the 3D gives me trouble. The route I took was that I am taking all the triangles of the mesh one by one,I am drawing lines from my point to all the vertices of the triangle, if the line intersects with any triangle I continue if it does not then I add the triangle to the new mesh. I know it is not perfect but even that does not work properly. Is there an algorithm for that kind of process ?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "drawing lines from my point to all the vertices of the triangle", what is "my point".   This sounds like a different problem than the one you asked, which is "find the points inside a given mesh...", whereas this seems to be the question "is this vertex visible to all mesh triangles.   So which one are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually , I would create a grid in 3d space and repeat the process for every point. That is how I thought of it, I did not know how to proceed and I still don't to be honest.